# Поменять классы у двух элементов при клике

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

написал скрипт, который при клике меняет классы между двумя элементами. Но мне не нравится его реализация - слишком в лоб. Как его оптимизировать?

```js
$('.product__size-control-item').on('click', function() {
  const i = $(this).parent().find('.product__size-control-item').index($(this));

  const selector = $(this).parent().find('.product__size-control-selector');
  selector.css('transform', 'translateX(' + 100 * i + '%');

  $(this).parent().find('.product__size-control-item').removeClass('active');

  $(this).parent().find('.product__size-control-item').children().removeClass('not_selected_item mt-1 selected_item mt-2');
  $(this).parent().find('.product__size-control-item').children().addClass('not_selected_item mt-2');

  $(this).find('h5').removeClass('not_selected_item mt-2');
  $(this).find('h5').addClass('selected_item mt-1');

  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.selected_item{
    font-family: Comic Sans MS, Medium, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.not_selected_item{
    font-family: Comic Sans MS, Medium, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
}
  
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #878686;
}

::-moz-placeholder {
    color: #878686;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #878686;
}

:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #878686;
}

::-ms-clear, ::-ms-reveal {
    display: none;
}

.product__size-control {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 0 16px;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #f1f2f5;
    border-radius: 100px;
}

.product__size-control-selector {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: -webkit-transform .2s ease-out;
    transition: transform .2s ease-out;
    transition: transform .2s ease-out, -webkit-transform .2s ease-out;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #babfd0;
    border-radius: 100px;
}

.product__size-control-item {
    list-style: none;
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 100px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    height: 38px;
    width: 100%;
    color: rgba(55, 53, 53, .7);
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 26px;
    font-family: Dodo Medium, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    transition: color .2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product__size-control">
  <div class="product__size-control-selector"></div>
  <div class="product__size-control-item active" value="one">
    <h5 class="selected_item mt-1">35&nbsp;см</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="product__size-control-item" value="two">
    <h5 class="not_selected_item mt-2">25&nbsp;см</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).find('h5').toggleClass('not_selected_item mt-2 selected_item mt-1');
//$(this).find('h5').addClass('selected_item mt-1');
```

```js
$('.product__size-control-item').on('click', function() {
  const i = $(this).parent().find('.product__size-control-item').index($(this));

  const selector = $(this).parent().find('.product__size-control-selector');
  selector.css('transform', 'translateX(' + 100 * i + '%');

  $(this).parent().find('.product__size-control-item').children().removeClass('not_selected_item mt-1 selected_item mt-2').addClass('not_selected_item mt-2');

  $(this).find('h5').toggleClass('not_selected_item mt-2 selected_item mt-1');

  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.selected_item{
    font-family: Comic Sans MS, Medium, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.not_selected_item{
    font-family: Comic Sans MS, Medium, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
}
  
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #878686;
}

::-moz-placeholder {
    color: #878686;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #878686;
}

:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #878686;
}

::-ms-clear, ::-ms-reveal {
    display: none;
}

.product__size-control {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 0 16px;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #f1f2f5;
    border-radius: 100px;
}

.product__size-control-selector {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: -webkit-transform .2s ease-out;
    transition: transform .2s ease-out;
    transition: transform .2s ease-out, -webkit-transform .2s ease-out;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #babfd0;
    border-radius: 100px;
}

.product__size-control-item {
    list-style: none;
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 100px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    height: 38px;
    width: 100%;
    color: rgba(55, 53, 53, .7);
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 26px;
    font-family: Dodo Medium, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    transition: color .2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product__size-control">
  <div class="product__size-control-selector"></div>
  <div class="product__size-control-item active" value="one">
    <h5 class="selected_item mt-1">35&nbsp;см</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="product__size-control-item" value="two">
    <h5 class="not_selected_item mt-2">25&nbsp;см</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: я думал над таким решением, но это работает не корректно <https://jsfiddle.net/Slav4ka/L0us3zm8/6/>. Да и эта функция срабатывает, если нажать на текущий элемент (положение бегунка не изменяется)

Comment: @СлаваИванов Сделайте работающий пример (в вопросе), который показывает жалемое поведение.

Comment: @СлаваИванов желаемое

Comment: @ Igor - сделал

Comment: @СлаваИванов Что должно происходить при клике на активный элемент?

Comment: @ Igor ничего не должно происходить

Comment: @СлаваИванов По-моему, ничего и не происходит.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94833/discussion-between---and-igor).